# Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS NIC Drivers work, Alt 18.04.2 NIC Drivers don't work

Tags: drivers, 18.04, raid, nic

DHCP seems to work just fine with the normal LTS server iso.  However the drivers on the LTS (Bionic Beaver) don't allow DHCP to work, and I can only ping some local addresses.

The goal is to have my boot disk be built on a software RAID 1, hence using Bionic Beaver.

My best guess for how to proceed is to copy the drivers from the main LTS iso to the LTS Bionic Beaver iso.
Where are NIC drivers in the iso's folder structure?
Is this the best way to go about this?

Comment: The server and desktop versions of 18.04 use the same drivers, so copying them will not help.  You probably have a configuration issue -- compare the two setups. What does raid have to do with your DHCP not working?

Comment: RAID shouldn't have anything to do with the DHCP not working.  
I tried installing using the 18.04 LTS server iso, which apparently doesn't support RAID for the boot disk.  DHCP worked on that, but RAID for boot disk isn't given as an option during installation.  
I tried installing using the 18.04 LTS server Bionic Beaver iso.  DHCP doesn't work, but RAID is an option during installation.